# Flatten the array of nested jsons with dynamic mapping, problem with backslash before double quote in JSON

Tags: json, variables, double-quotes, backslash

I am currently working on transferring data from a REST API in Azure Data Factory. The data is presented in the form of an array of nested JSONs, and my goal is to copy it into a CSV file. To achieve this, I have implemented a loop for the array and dynamic content for the mapping of the copy activity.

I am utilizing a Pipelines_Mappings variable to generate a flexible mapping. Here is part of the Pipelines_Mappings variable

```
"type": "TabularTranslator",
        "mappings": [{
                "source": {
                    "path": "$['results'][0]['label']"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "ordinal": 1
                }
            }
```

Within the loop, a set variable activity is employed to modify the Pipelines_Mappings variable to replace the index [0] with the loop index item(). Then, the updated variable is assigned to the Modified_Mappings variable. Eventually, I utilize the Modified_Mappings variable in the copy activity and set the mapping tab of the copy activity as @json(Modified_Mappings).

But the problem is when I use the set variable to manipulate the JSON string, backslashes are added before each double quote. This causes issues with the JSON and the copy doesn't work correctly. How can I remove these backslashes?

when I used the Pipelines_Mappings without any changes in the copy activity, it works.